# SQL Join to only 1 row - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have an AllocatedStock table holding a case number (knows as a TPND) and a quantity. I need to select a list of product stock but present this with the product number (known as TPNB) rather than the case number. I also have a ProductLookup table which holds all TPNBs and TPNDs.

**AllocatedStock**
AllocatedStockID  identity
TPND  int
Quantity int

**ProductLookup**
ProductLookupID  identity
TPND  int
TPNB  int

There are a number of product types (TPNB) that can be provided in more that one case type (TPND). This the required result is total number of each product type held, I used a sum() function as follows:

```
select TPNB, sum(AllocatedQty) as 'QTY'
from integration.ProductLookup as PL 
inner join  dbo.AllocatedStock as AStock
on PL.TPND = AStock.TPND
group by TPNB
```

Unfortunately, the ProductLookup table contains some duplicate rows (historic bad data that can't be cleaned up) where a row contains the same TPND and TPNB as another row. The only thing I need to join to the ProductLookup table for is to get the TPNB for the TPND that I have in the AllocatedStock table. Is there any way to get the join to select only the 1st match? The problem I have at present is that for TPNDs that have a duplicate row in the ProductLookup table I get back double the quantity value.

Would be grateful for any help,

Thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a whirl. I am using a derived query to 'clean' your productlookup table.

```
 select TPNB, sum(AllocatedQty) as 'QTY'
    from (select distinct TPND, TPNB from integration.ProductLookup) as PL 
    inner join  dbo.AllocatedStock as AStock
    on PL.TPND = AStock.TPND
    group by TPNB
```

Comment: Damn, you guys are fast on this!

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT DISTINCT` should do it:

```
select TPNB, sum(AllocatedQty) as 'QTY'
from (SELECT DISTINCT TPND, TPNB FROM integration.ProductLookup) as PL 
inner join  dbo.AllocatedStock as AStock
on PL.TPND = AStock.TPND
group by TPNB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct tpnb, qty
from (
select TPNB, sum(AllocatedQty) as 'QTY'
from integration.ProductLookup as PL 
inner join  dbo.AllocatedStock as AStock
on PL.TPND = AStock.TPND
group by ProductLookupID ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TPNB, sum(AllocatedQty) as 'QTY'
from 
(
    SELECT TPND, TPNB
    FROM ProductLookup
    GROUP BY TPND, TPNB
) as PL 
inner join  dbo.AllocatedStock as AStock
on PL.TPND = AStock.TPND
group by TPNB
```